# How can I modify my save function to do both save user / edit user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want  my save function to do 2 things :

1.Save user in table - Done

2.Update user in table - Not Done

Save function code:

```
var buildUser = function () {
    $('#save').click(function () {
        var newUser = {};

        $('#myForm').find('input[type!=button]').each(function () {
            var value = $(this).val();
            var name = $(this).attr('id');
            newUser[name] = value;
        });
        //i think here will be an if condition but i dont know how
        buildRow(newUser);
        userData.push(newUser);

        $("#myForm")[0].reset();
    });
};
```

Here is the entire code : http://jsfiddle.net/Shakerwtd/e9273/

The date is taken from a json file.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways you can do this, what does your HTML look like?

One way to do this is to assign ids to users.

1. Build an ID-generator service. Simple thing, just give unique id, kind of like this:

   var GeneratorModule = (function() {

   ```
   var generator;

   function init() {
       var id = 0;
       function getId() {
           return id++;
       }
       return {
           getId: getId
       };
   }
   return  {
       getGenerator: function() {
           if(!generator) {
               generator = init();
           }
           return generator;
       }
   };
   ```

   });

You would get the generator with idGenerator = GeneratorModule().getGenerator();

then you can idGenerator.getId(); each time you build new id.

1. Have your initial Save button take that ID and provide that also to the buildRow.
2. Have the buildRow also save the id at the tr level, like `<tr id="tr-12345">`
3. Have the Save button for the edited row also have this id, like id=12345.
4. Your `//i think here will be an if condition but i dont know how` should check if there is the id on the save. If there is, then do not call buildRow, but updateRow.
5. updateRow will, obviously, find the row with the id="tr-12345". (`tr-` part because you can't have two of the same ids on the page, obviously.)

Comment: If you click on this link http://jsfiddle.net/Shakerwtd/e9273/ you`ll see entire code .

Comment: On update somehow i recreate the row on the same position :-?